# Desktop application not able to connect to web services

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a desktop application it uses web-services to communicate with the databases. It was running fine but suddenly after a couple of restarts on the server end the application is unable to connect to the web-services. now it shows the following error in the debugging mode "The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception."

[image]

Comment: Do you reference in app.config any assembly with version provided? Maybe it is because upgrade of some libraries that happened during server restarts..

Comment: @KonradKokosa: i have checked the app.config and the binding references are there.

Comment: Check the inner exception for more details

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : checked the inner exception it said "{"Configuration system failed to initialize"}" i dug it up and some solution suggested that order of my app.config might not be right, but it was,.,.

Comment: @AychJay See if inner exception contains nested inner exception. It should be. That will tell you what's wrong with the config file.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : i checked the inner exception nested in the inner exception : it says that the solution has issue with my userSettings Tag